# Multiple bars with same category name show differently based on array of arrays or array of objects

Tags: echarts

I noticed that using

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [ {
        type: 'bar',
        data: [
            { name: 'Sun', value: 50 },
            { name: 'Sun', value: 80 },
            { name: 'Mon', value: 100 }
        ]
    }]
}
```

There are two bars with category as 'Sun'. But if I use

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        data: [
            ['Sun',50],
            ['Sun',80],
            ['Mon',100]
            ]
    }]
}
```

I see only one bar for 'Sun' with both data elements overlapping. Why does it work with array of objects differently? Also, if instead of using inline data, if I use dataset, then both array of arrays and array of objects behave the same where there is only one bar with overlap.

The reason I am looking for clarity on this is, I have a visualMap with a different attribute for color which makes the data repeat. I am trying to figure out if I need to create separate series or use the same series.

Answer (score 0):

In general is bad idea to naming data points the same name. Strange that the data in the first case did not merge... If you need make the group then in the Echarts it's named `stack`. For the `stack` you can use the same name and it will be joined into one group.

VisualMap usually the global option and affects all series but you can limit with `seriesIndex`.

```js
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

  var option = {
    xAxis: {
      data: ["Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4", "Cat5", "Cat6"]
    },
    visualMap: {
      type: 'continuous',
      range: [0, 70],
      seriesIndex: 2,
      color: ['green', 'blue', 'red'],
    },
    yAxis: {},
    series: [{
      name: 'Series1',
      stack: 'group1',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20],
      color: 'lightgray'
    }, {
      name: 'Series2',
      stack: 'group1',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20],
      color: 'gray'
    }, {
      name: 'Series3',
      stack: 'group2',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [50, 20, 70, 10, 60, 40],
    }]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.9.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```